# Extracting data from form element

Tags: php, selenium, behat, mink

How can I get 123 from `<strong id="reference">123</strong>`?

Something like below.

```
/**
 * @Then /^I check reference in database$/
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function checkReferenceInDb()
{
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $page = $session->getPage();

    $element = $page->find('css', //I think I should do something here to process the page content);

    if (null === $element) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Could not evaluate CSS element"));
    }

    $id = //123 should be assigned to this and I'll do the rest
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shortcut [`findById()`](https://github.com/Behat/en-mink.behat.org/blob/master/index.rst#find-methods):

```
$element = $page->findById('reference');
```

Then, use [`getText()`](https://github.com/Behat/en-mink.behat.org/blob/master/index.rst#element-content-and-text) to get the text from an element:

```
$id = $element->getText();
```

Comment: Thank you. Works as expected.